# How can I update an element in array that is an object in array inside mongoDb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb collection that contains this type of structure.

`modules: [
        { 
            systems:[
              { systemId: 13, count: 2 },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 },
              { systemId: 8, count: 1 }
            ]
        },
        { 
            systems:[
              { systemId: 13, count: 2 },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 }
            ]
        }
    ]`

what I am trying to do is `update` every `module` that contains a `system` with `systemId = 13` and `$set` that entire system to `{d: null}`

so that it looks like this afterwards:

`modules: [
        { 
            systems:[
              { d: null },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 },
              { systemId: 8, count: 1 }
            ]
        },
        { 
            systems:[
              { d: null },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 }
            ]
        }
    ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have nested arrays, this won't be possible as a single query until the feature request from [SERVER-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) is added.  Once nested `$elemMatch` operators are allowed then your update would look something like below. **Note: this does not currently work, and the syntax is not yet even defined - it is for illustrative purposes only**:

```
db.foo.update(
    {modules: {$elemMatch: { systems: {$elemMatch: {systemId : 13}}}}}, 
    { $set : {"modules.$0.systems.$1" : {d : null}}}
);
```

The find piece of the query works currently, but the update piece will not allow for multiple positional operators even if you revert to just the current `$` from the theoretical `$0` and `$1`.

Even then you would run into the first element match limitation on $elemMatch (it does not match multiple/all elements, just the first one it finds), hence you would potentially have to run this multiple times to update all the docs, at least until [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) is done.

To illustrate how this would work with a single array is pretty straightforward, let's insert your sample doc and drop the modules field:

```
db.bar.insert([{ 
            systems:[
              { systemId: 13, count: 2 },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 },
              { systemId: 8, count: 1 }
            ]
        },
        { 
            systems:[
              { systemId: 13, count: 2 },
              { systemId: 20, count: 7 }
            ]
        }
    ]);
```

That essentially creates two document (it treats each element in the array as a doc to be inserted). So, we have 2 docs now:

```
> db.bar.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e0708e1b8924251e1330"), "systems" : [ { "systemId" : 13, "count" : 2 }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 }, { "systemId" : 8, "count" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e0708e1b8924251e1331"), "systems" : [ { "systemId" : 13, "count" : 2 }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 } ] }
```

To update these docs as outlined (as long as there is only a single match for `systemId : 13`, you can then do the following:

```
>db.bar.update(
    { systems: {$elemMatch: {systemId : 13}}}, 
    { $set : {"systems.$" : {d : null}}},
    {multi : true}
);
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 2 })
```

Let's look at our docs again:

```
> db.bar.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e1198e1b8924251e1332"), "systems" : [ { "d" : null }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 }, { "systemId" : 8, "count" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e1198e1b8924251e1333"), "systems" : [ { "d" : null }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 } ] }
```

Can you get your data into this format, even temporarily?  Yes, but it means a new collection:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {modules: {$elemMatch: { "systems": {$elemMatch: {"systemId" : 13}}}}}},
    {$unwind : "$modules"},
    {$project : {"_id" : 0, "systems" : "$modules.systems"}},
    {$out : "flattened_systems"}    
])
// confirm the new doc structure
db.flattened_systems.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e4702127b5e51e8a9e0a"), "systems" : [ { "systemId" : 13, "count" : 2 }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 }, { "systemId" : 8, "count" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e4702127b5e51e8a9e0b"), "systems" : [ { "systemId" : 13, "count" : 2 }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 } ] }
```

Then, you can run the update above to modify the `systemIds` and re-aggregate to get back to the original structure:

```
db.flattened_systems.update(
    { systems: {$elemMatch: {systemId : 13}}}, 
    { $set : {"systems.$" : {d : null}}},
    {multi : true}
);

db.flattened_systems.aggregate([
    {$group : { "_id" : 0, "modules" : {$push : {"systems" : "$systems"}}}},
    {$project : {"_id" : 0, "modules" : 1, "flag" : {$literal : "new"}}},
    {$out : "processed_systems"}    
])
```

So, the `processed_systems` collection now has the doc in the format you want (the additional "new" flag is optional to show how you might flag as updated):

```
> db.processed_systems.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450e9e92127b5e51e8a9e10"), "modules" : [ { "systems" : [ { "d" : null }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 }, { "systemId" : 8, "count" : 1 } ] }, { "systems" : [ { "d" : null }, { "systemId" : 20, "count" : 7 } ] } ], "flag" : "new" }
```

Not ideal, particularly if the docs are being actively updated (no way to do this atomically) but hopefully it gives you an idea of how you might go about this in the interim.  I'm pretty sure you could do this with Map Reduce also, but it might be better to  ask that as a separate question.